# Excel: remove duplicate results of TEXTJOIN formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I remove all the duplicates out of the results of the following formula:

```
=IF(C2<>"";TEXTJOIN("; ";TRUE;IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2;$A$2:$A$6));$B$2:$B$6;""));"")
```

See Cell D2 in the picture below for an example

[image: example]

My version of Excel doesn't have the `Unique` function.

Comment: Couldn't you make the search list unique first? Then your function should work

Comment: you mean change it manually?

Comment: You could remove the duplicates from column A and B with Data -> Remove Duplicates. Then use your function and search list on the unique list.

Comment: that wouldn't work, each name can have multiple numbers and sometime different names can have same number. furthermore the data is fixed, so i can't changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use `FILTERXML` and use an `XPATH` expression to return unique nodes:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2,$A$2:$A$6)),$B$2:$B$6,""))&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding::*=.)]")),"")
```

Here we check for all `<s>` child-nodes and exclude them if any preceding sibling is the same.

Another option would be to avoid the nested `IF` and let `XPATH` do all the work. Might be an option if you'd have a reasonable list (not massive):

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTERXML("<x><t>"&TEXTJOIN("</s></t><t>",,B$2:B$6&"<s>"&A$2:A$6)&"</s></t></x>","//t[.//*[contains(.,'"&C2&"')]][not(preceding::*=.)]")),"")
```

Here we check for all `<t>` nodes and check if their child node contains our search value. Furthermore it does the same check on duplicates as before.